# Multiple lockable resources with same name label in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, resources, label

My issue is with Lockable Resources in Jenkins. I have currently two nodes `"nodeA"` and `"nodeB"`, each node have an USB Dongle on it which can be defined as a lockable resource.

Some jenkins jobs can be launched only if the USB Dongle is available. So what I want to achieve, having two jenkins job running simultaneously with each dongle whenevever a node/dongle_usb is free.

I created two lockable ressources `"USB_dongle"` and `"USB_dongle2"` with a label for each called for example `"usb_label"`, I want it to be the same label for the two lockable ressources because I don't care on which node it will be launched and I want to have both jobs running together. But the issue is that when a job start on a node, it will lock the two `"usb_dongle"` & `"usb_dongle2"` lockable resources, because the label `"usb_dongle"` is in each lockable resource. How can I keep the same label name on my jobs and have them run simultaneously on the two nodes. Because currently, one node lock the two lockables resources and the other wait the `"usb_label"` to be free. I would like to have jenkins to understand that the two labels `"usb_label"` with the same name are "different".

In this example take "USB_dongle" as "GHS_dongle":
Node configuration :
[image: Node Configuration]

[image: Node configuration 2]

Job configuration : Project can only be executed on node with "ghs" label and also need the "ghs_dongle" label lockable resources

[image: Job configuration]
[image: Lockable ressources]

Lockables resources :
[image: Lockable resources]

Comment: Please enhance the question by adding 2 images, one of each node configuration. Would like to see how you have configured labels too.

Comment: @mdabdullah edit done

Comment: You have a resource constraint which is causing concurrency issue. Your labels are fine and by design is is supposed to lock the system. Can you test what happens if you put `Number of executors= 2` for both the nodes? I want to find out if the `lock` is applied at the `executor` level or the whole `node`.

Comment: With 1 it works well as wanted thanks a lot :)

Comment: Delighted! Please upvote my previous comment and mark this question as `answered` with your answer itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added 1 to number of resources to request and it works! (Was 0 before so took all resources) Thanks @mdabdullah
[image]